# Is this function built in in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7

Suppose I have two lists of the same size in Python, the first:

```
[100, 200, 300, 400]
```

and I want the other to be:

```
[0, 100, 300, 600]
```

which is each element in the 2nd list equals the sum of all previous elements in the first.

Is there a built-in Python function that does such an operation on a list? Or do I have to think about an algorithm to do it?

Comment: I don't think such a function exists. You can write a simple function to do that

Comment: Nope, no built-in for that in 2.x.

Comment: Are you intentionally ignoring the last element of the first list? A more logical result would be `[0, 100, 300, 600, 1000]`, or even simply `[100, 300, 600, 1000]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 3.2+, you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> a_list = [100, 200, 300, 400]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([0] + a_list[:-1]))
[0, 100, 300, 600]
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid creation of temporary list, use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, accumulate, islice
>>>
>>> a_list = [100, 200, 300, 400]
>>> list(accumulate(chain([0], islice(a_list, 0, len(a_list) - 1))))
[0, 100, 300, 600]
```

Comment: `accumulate(chain([0], islice(a_list, 0, -1))` would avoid creation of two temporary lists, for people who care about that kind of things. BTW ignoring the last element of the list seems like a mistake in the question, for which I've asked the submitter for clarification.

Comment: @user4815162342, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to you. BTW, `itertools.islice` does not accept negative index.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The price for increased efficiency is (as is frequently the case) less readable code. But I still believe the OP didn't really intend to ignore the last element of the input list. :)